# How to do the progress bar just like Nuxt when webpack building

Tags: webpack, nuxt.js

I am using `Nuxt`, and I am curious about the progress bar shown in the console during build:

[image: screenshot]

Is this a plugin of Webpack? Where can I find this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a Webpack plugin: [`nuxt/webpackbar`](https://github.com/nuxt/webpackbar).

Nuxt uses it in [`packages/webpack/src/config/base.js`](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/blob/0610f0b/packages/webpack/src/config/base.js#L395-L426):

```js
// Build progress indicator
plugins.push(new WebpackBar({
  name: this.name,
  color: this.colors[this.name],
  reporters: [
    'basic',
    'fancy',
    'profile',
    'stats'
  ],
  basic: !buildOptions.quiet && env.minimalCLI,
  fancy: !buildOptions.quiet && !env.minimalCLI,
  profile: !buildOptions.quiet && buildOptions.profile,
  stats: !buildOptions.quiet && !this.dev && buildOptions.stats,
  reporter: {
    change: (_, { shortPath }) => {
      if (!this.isServer) {
        nuxt.callHook('bundler:change', shortPath)
      }
    },
    done: (buildContext) => {
      if (buildContext.hasErrors) {
        nuxt.callHook('bundler:error')
      }
    },
    allDone: () => {
      nuxt.callHook('bundler:done')
    },
    progress ({ statesArray }) {
      nuxt.callHook('bundler:progress', statesArray)
    }
  }
}))
```